# Does SaxonCE support regex flag "!"?

Tags: regex, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have xsl stylesheet that uses flag `!` a lot. I found that very handy since xpath 2.0 specification limits regular expressions usage.

This stylesheet was intended to be used in web-based application (php) for transforming user input data and generating output, so SaxonCE came to my mind. But it throws error **`unrecognized flag '!'`** .

So, is there way around this? Does Saxon/C support ! flag at least? Or the best way is to use SaxonHE and somehow connect it with web app?

EDIT:
To be clear, `!` is special flag used in Saxon products that tells xslt processor to use his own regex engine instead of xpath one, It is not w3c recommendation, more like extra feature.

Comment: Can you show us some detail as to what you think that flag `!` does? The specification http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#flags defines flags `s`, `i`, `m` and `x`.

Comment: I edited my question with clarification

Comment: If it doesn't violate your company's (or whatever) policy, can you show us an example?

Comment: Please clarify whether the question is about Saxon/C or Saxon-CE. Although the names are similar (sorry!) they are quite different things.

Comment: Well, I wanted to use Saxon CE with my web app but only if it supports `!`. So I moved and installed Saxon\C on my server, which works perfectly. I just wanted to know if there is some solution to make it work on SaxonCE too.